# Stored procedure output parameter using sp_executesql returning null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlclient

I'm trying to determine why a db call in .Net is failing with an output parameter.  I'm using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) ORM to make the call and this is a bare bones sample of the trace.  It uses `sp_executesql` to parametrize the call and I think there lies the problem with the output parameter.

Consider this code:

```
CREATE PROC test
    @addressId INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
    -- using select and set to see if if makes a difference using either
    select @addressId = 1
    SET @addressId = 1
GO

declare @p3 int
set @p3=NULL
exec sp_executesql N'test',N'@addressId int output',@addressId=@p3 output
select @p3
```

I would expect `select @p3` to return 1, why does it return null?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here? This should be a straight forward stored procedure call....no dynamic sql needed.

Comment: It was an output for one of the traces.  I'm wondering now if it was a sqlText (instead of proc) call which caused that kind of sql.  I've got it working now using another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly declare `@addressId` as an output parameter in the stored procedure call in exactly the same way you would if you weren't using dynamic SQL:

```
declare @p3 int
set @p3=NULL
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC test @addressId=@addressId OUTPUT',N'@addressId int output',@addressId=@p3 output
select @p3
```

Without dynamic SQL, the code would have to be:

```
declare @p3 int
set @p3=NULL
EXEC test @addressId=@p3 OUTPUT
select @p3
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The app is sending the sql correctly now and the traces looks like the second example in your answer.  At least I know now what was missing from the original trace to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the problem is that the dynamic SQL isn't actually passing the parameter through.

However, in this instance, you don't actually need dynamic SQL at all.

```sql
declare @p3 int;
exec test @addressId=@p3 output;
select @p3;
```

---

**Furthermore, it's highly likely that you were simply using `SqlCommand` incorrectly.**

`SqlCommand.CommandType` defaults to `CommandType.Text` which explains why the above code was generated, as it expects that the text is an SQL batch rather than the name of a stored procedure. No error was generated because it's valid to call a procedure without using the keyword `EXEC`.

If you use `CommandType.StoredProcedure` then everything should just work.